# How to get the quantity of stock available for each of franchise based on stock transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

I need to get the total qty available for each franchise based on per item.

I have menu_catalog table which will link to main table of franchise and item table.

```
id   id_franchise   id_item
1    1              1
2    1              2
3    1              3
4    2              1
5    2              3
6    3              2
```

Each of the franchise might contain different items.

For the stock_transaction table

```
id  id_franchise  id_item  stock_in  stock_out  type  unit_price
1   1             1        10                   1     5.00
2   1             1                  2          2     5.00
3   2             3        10                   1     3.00

// type : 1 = stock in while 2 = stock out
```

Expected output :

```
id_item franchise1 franchise2 franchise3
1       8,40       0,0        0,0
2       0,0        0,0        0,0
3       0,0        10,30      0,0
```

I have a condition, when type = 1 then SUM the stock_in else SUM stock_out * -1, same for the price. I will store the total qty and total price for each item based on franchise.

I will select all item belong to this 3 franchises, even some item not existed on their menu catalog. The item not belong to the franchise will be return as 0.

p.s. the column of franchise is not fixed, will based on the id_franchise passed into the query.

How can i do this?

Comment: which version of mySQL DB are you using ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I am using phpMyAdmin, MySQL version is 5.6.

Comment: Do you use models and relationships?